# How long can my lightning node be safely offline?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon

I am interested in setting up a full bitcoin and lightning node on my pi.  I want to open a few channels and be well connected in the network.  I intend to keep this machine on permanently, but may have to unplug it if I need to move it to a different socket or maintain it.  How long can my node safely be off the bitcoin network without risking loss of funds in my channels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that depends on the locktime that is configured for your channels. taken from `c lightning` (c.f.: https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/blob/97118c558e84e0b3a12a8cbe60528ad5cfcb2fd6/doc/lightningd-config.5.txt )

> *watchtime-blocks*='BLOCKS'::
>       How long we need to spot an outdated close attempt: on opening a channel
>       we tell our peer that this is how long they'll have to wait if they perform
>       a unilateral close.
>
> *max-locktime-blocks*='BLOCKS'::
>       The longest our funds can be delayed (ie. the longest *watchtime-blocks*
>       our peer can ask for, and also the longest HTLC timeout we will accept).
>       If our peer asks for longer, we'll refuse to create a channel, and if an
>       HTLC asks for longer, we'll refuse it.

I believe the standard setting should be 144 blocks which statistically should be 24 hours. of course you should consider a safety window to be able to get your breach remedy tx mined in case of a unilateral close.