# Is it possible to change `their_to_self_delay` after a channel is open?

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning, locktime

Rene said [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/78156/112185) that a c-lightning node is safe for around 24 hours to be offline (depending on the locktime). This is set with `watchtime-blocks` in the configuration file of c-ligthning. But this will only be used for **new** channels, as far as I understand.

Is it possible to change the `their_to_self_delay` value of a already existing channel?

The `their_to_self_delay` value is equal to `watchtime-blocks` value set in the general c-lightning config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think as of now the protocol does not support updating those channel parameters as they would need to be renegotiated. I could not find any message in the Protocol that would support such a functionality

What you could do is to close the channel and reopen it But I guess you would want to avoid it and technically I do not see reasons why such an updated should be impossible.

Comment: You are right, i want to avoid closing channels to change those channel parameters. The process to get this implemented in the different node distributions would be to have a new  BOLT or is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: To be able for two nodes to do this, they would need a protocol. Thus an extension of the BOLTs would probably be necessary. At least I don't see any other way